# "intersect" several transformations

Tags: ros, publish, transformations

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a node that will lookafter two transformations. My problem is that both have different frequencies and I with the information os these two I have to publish a new one. So I want to know what is the best way to publish the new one, what timestamp should I define to the new one for example.

Thanks for your help

Pedro

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35025/%22intersect%22-several-transformations/) by [PedroS.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2042/pedros./) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2012-05-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are willing to dig into code, the [robot_pose_ekf code](https://kforge.ros.org/navigation/navigation/file/9c5654f8e598/robot_pose_ekf/src/odom_estimation_node.cpp) shows how to combine different data streams.

A rough idea:
Look at all time stamps from all incoming data eg. time_A, time_B, time_C. Pick those that are not too old (ie within your timeout range from current_time). Finally, use the min of the valid timestamps vs current_time eg. if time_C is outside the timeout range, your output timestamp will be min(current_time, time_A, time_B)

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1